# Cannot import ExampleData/dialing.m4a in mma version 11.2.0.0

Tags: import, sound

I cannot import MPEG-4 audio, whether it be the example file provided, or any other M4A file I have.  The documentation clearly states that this should work, but here's what I get when I try it.

```
In[319]:= Import["ExampleData/dialing.m4a"]
During evaluation of In[319]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as M4A format.
Out[319]= $Failed
```

Is there anyone out there who can import MP4 audio in version 11.2.00, and if so, how are you getting it done?

Comment: This doesn't immediately answer your question, but your code works fine in MMA 11.3 (Win7 64bit). Perhaps you can upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, MarcoB.  I did upgrade, and 11.3 will import MPEG-4 audio -- sort of.  It seems as if the import fails on every other invocation (or possibly some other more complex situation, maybe having to do with changing or not changing the file being imported).